# Error trying to use Vagrant up with Virtual Box

Tags: terminal, vagrant

I have installed homestead with Vagrant in my MacOS. I have installed all with Virtual Box, but when i try to use `vagrant up` command in my terminal for running Virtual Machine appear this error:

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Lorenzo:~ lorenzomammi$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise32'...
Progress: 90%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/Users/lorenzomammi/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32/1.0.0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "precise32_1576225284920_5564", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "11", "--disk", "/Users/sybercodesign/VirtualBox VMs/precise32_1576225284920_5564/precise32-disk001.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /Users/lorenzomammi/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32/1.0.0/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057) - Invalid argument value (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg *)" at line 957 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Can anyone help me? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to come to this late, but I just encountered the same issue. Various answers on the web suggest it's due to lack of hard disk space. In my case I found that I'd changed the Virtualbox "Default Machine Folder" setting to use an external hard drive that wasn't connected at the time I was trying to create a new machine. Worth checking those two possibilities!

Comment: Yes thanks I have already solved this problem by going to update the root folder of Virtual Box

Comment: @Laurenz mind sharing what you mean by updating the root folder of Virtual Box?